# Protobuf marshallers not registering when using Gradle?

Tags: protocol-buffers, quarkus, infinispan

I have a project where I'm trying to get protobuf to work with infinispan, quarkus and gradle. The problem is that although I'm following the instructions given in the Quarkus homepage: https://quarkus.io/guides/infinispan-client, it seems that when I'm using gradle, the marshallers are not generated and registered as they should be. To me it seems like this comes down to the `org.infinispan.protostream:protostream-processor` not executing when gradle is the build tool. Is this a conscious decision that only Maven is supported, or am I missing something obvious in my gradle setup?

Replications of the most simple cases can be found here: https://github.com/radiosphere/gradle-java-protobuf for gradle and here for maven: https://github.com/radiosphere/mvn-java-protobuf. These projects are extremely basic, basically trying to run a simple code on startup:

```java
    public void onStartup(@Observes StartupEvent startupEvent) {
        RemoteCache<String, CounterState> cache = cacheManager.administration().getOrCreateCache("default", DefaultTemplate.DIST_SYNC);

        cache.put("a", new CounterState(2L));
        CounterState state = cache.get("a");

        logger.infof("State: %s", state);
    }
```

In the maven project this works, in the gradle project an exception is thrown saying that no marshaller can be found. Apart from build tool choice the projects should be identical.

Comment: For anyone that comes here that are using Kotlin you might be interested in this link: https://github.com/radiosphere/gradle-kotlin-protobuf . It's an example where the infinispan annotation processor is configured for gradle / kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotation processor runs in the Maven build because `io.quarkus:quarkus-infinispan-client` has a `compile` dependency on `org.infinispan.protostream:protostream-processor`.

Looks like Gradle [made a decision to not use annotation processors found in the compile classpath](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_compile_avoidance):

> Since implementation details matter for annotation processors, they must be declared separately on the annotation processor path. Gradle ignores annotation processors on the compile classpath.

That means you have to add an explicit `annotationProcessor` dependency:

```
    annotationProcessor 'org.infinispan.protostream:protostream-processor:4.4.0.Final'
```